# image_picker huge delay on returning multiple objects

Tags: flutter, flutter-image-picker

there.

I'm trying to do a simple implementation of image_picker so my user can select multiple media files as `selectedMedia = await imagePicker.pickMultipleMedia();`. The problem is that if anything beyond 5 pictures or a 10sec video is selected the tome it takes to process that line goes above 5secs and depending on the video size, it can go as high as 20-30secs.

I can´t run it inside an isolate because the function interacts with both UI and background processing. I tried several different libraries and all of them face the same issue and don't provide a callback so I can be proactive and update the UI with intermediary information (e.g. add place holders for the new media selected).

Does any one has an idea on how to provide a fast UI update for user without having to wait for the whole media processing?

This is the complete function I'm using

```
Future<List<XFile>> getXFilesFromDevice() async {
    List<XFile> selectedMedia = [];
    try {
      selectedMedia = await imagePicker.pickMultipleMedia();
    } on Exception {
      throw MediaServiceException();
    }
    if (selectedMedia.isNotEmpty) {
      return selectedMedia;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can show placeholders immediately when `getXFilesFromDevice` is called. No need to await that function. Use `then` callback to update the UI to the returned value accordingly.

```dart
showPlaceholders();
getXFilesFromDevice()
    .then((selectedMedia) {
      // handle cases, update UI
    })
    .catchError(errorHandler);
```

Comment: That's what I'm planing to do as a workaround but event for the proposed `showPlaceholders();` I would ideally have the number of itens selected. 
To give you more info, the user is adding more media to an existent media library so, it would be odd present one single place holder if he/she have picked several different files.